# May the chemical energy of combustion be wholly released as photon only?

Tags: energy, photons, combustion

It may be the burning of wood, LPG gas, hydrogen, gasoline. The energy is released wholly as photon and it is the absorption of photon by matter that heats up everything else increasing their kinetic energy.

Comment: This does not sound as if you have studied the subject. A lot of the chemical energy ends up as kinetic energy of the molecules taking part in combustion .

Comment: Sounds hard to conserve energy and momentum…

Comment: It is the easy part to just say combustion releases "heat energy", but can someone go deeper than this 10th grade answer. Heat is basically kinetic energy 1/2mv².

Answer (score 2):

Chemical reactions that directly emit photons do exist, see [Chemiluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemiluminescence) or search for "chemically pumped lasers". Note that these generally release heat as well.

In order to implement your proposed mechanism, in the first place you need an impressively opaque media where your chemical reaction takes place. Otherwise, the reaction energy will escape far away before it initiates the next portions of the substances into the reaction.

As a counterexample, think about the chemical reaction at the gas stove.

It happens in a media visibly transparent to photons way above the energy scale of the reaction, as well as all the way down to near zero energy photons. You can even see one flamelet through another one. Still, your proposed "reaction photons" manage to get themselves absorbed and converted to heat? Quite a contradiction, so maybe this is not the way this particular chemical reaction happens.

Another consideration would be the flame spectra: one may expect few spectral lines, corresponding to main reaction mechanisms, to dominate the flame spectra? We see nothing like this. Flame spectra are either dominated by blackbody radiation (soot) or by few characteristic lines of known substances related to the reaction and not related to the energy transfers in the chemical reaction.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when a molecule gets oxidized, besides electrons moving about (producing some electromagnetic waves) the main effect is that the involved molecules change shape/type. This typically involves a gain in kinetic energy, which will be turned into heat when they collide with something (later producing more photons due to blackbody radiation from hot matter).

While it might be physically possible to constrain oxidation so that there is just electron transfer (e.g. imagine a nanomachine holding the substrate and oxidiser rigidly in place in a tiny raection chamber with space for just the two molecules while performing a isentropic change of the potential so there is no thermal jiggling), any form of unconstrained reaction will activate many degrees of freedom (photons, motion, rotation, internal oscillations). By the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem), energy will (once equilibrium sets in) be distributed equally between these modes. That means that some will escape as thermal excitations.

So I expect the general case is "no", especially for processes anything like what we normally regard as burning. Still, strongly constrained combustion like in nanopores has odd properties and might well produce a lot more output in some degrees of freedom than the above handwavy argument would suggest.